# How to filter data by dates in Charts.js

Tags: javascript, filter, charts, chart.js

I am using charts.js and I have line chart.
I am trying to filter data by label (date).
I have created two input start and end date input.
when user change start/end date chart should be filtered by date

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var lbls = ["07/11/2020","07/12/2020","07/13/2020",];
var dt = ["27","24","30",]


var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: 'line', // also try bar or other graph types

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: lbls,
    // Information about the dataset
    datasets: [{
      label: "Gold Price",
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      borderColor: 'royalblue',
      data: dt,
    }]
  },

  // Configuration options
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: 10,
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Gold Price"
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Price in USD'
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="chart" style="width:100%">
   <input type="date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" placeholder="Start Date" id="start"><input type="date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" placeholder="End Date" id="end">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
      
      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
```

that is my code, I have no idea how can I do that.

Comment: can you include momentjs in your project ? one aproach could be treating them as objects, so create an array of objects by populating it with your data ex:-> [{label:"01/02/2020",data:"10"},{}.....], apply filtering logic, and once its done parse it and pass it to the chartjs component. do some attempt and i will be happy to help with your code

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus my code is here on jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/gut9mkpf/ can you update what u mean?

Comment: you have 2 blank inputs without a triger, without any filter logic attempts, asking for ready code is not a good practice.

Comment: I already mentioned that I have no idea how can I do something, that's bad practice? I just want direction, I don't understand of you

Comment: that's the point bro, try reading the community guidelines, and then google: "filter javascript array of objects", "momentjs", "momentjs isbetween dates". It is hard only in the beggining

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<input type="date" id="startdate" value="2020-11-07" @onchange="filterDataOnDate"/>
<input type="date" id="enddate" value="2020-11-13" @onchange="filterDataOnDate" />


//Filter date
function filterDataOnDate(){
    const date = [...labels]
    const startdate = document.getElementById('startdate')
    const enddate = document.getElementById('enddate')

    //get the index number  in array
    const indexstartdate = date.indexOf(startdate.value);
    const indexenddate = date.indexOf(enddate.value);

    //slice the array
    const filterdate = date.slice(indexstartdate, indexenddate + 1);
    chart.config.data.labels = filterdate;

    //update the chart
    chart.update();
}
```